# Slicing a dataframe using matches to build a new dataframe with Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to get my code to take in a dataframe, find all occurrences of "START:", then iterate through each occurrence to create 'slices' (Where the first row is the "START:" match, and captures all the rows between where the last row is the "END:" that matches the string after "START:").

I want this to be put into a new dataframe where every 'slice' is separated by a blank row.

I can't seem to get it to work without it being ridiculously slow when scaling up my sheet to larger sizes (750,000 rows).

I'm unsure how else to approach my problem or how I can make it faster so large dataframes don't slow it to a crawl.

My df:

[image]

My code that where I think my issue or bad methodology is:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({}, columns = df.columns)

new_df = new_df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)

for value in list_of_commands:
    if 'Start: ' in value:
        value_to_match = value[6:]
        idx_start = df[df[col_name_source].str.contains(value_to_match, na = False)].first_valid_index()
        idx_end = df[df[col_name_source].str.contains(value_to_match, na = False)].last_valid_index()
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df.loc[idx_start:idx_end, :]]) 
        new_df = new_df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)
```

Whole program:

```
import pandas as pd
sheets_index = [
    ('Numbers_', '0'), ('Numbers_', '1'), ('Numbers_', '2'), ('Numbers_', '3'),
    ('Numbers_1', '0'), ('Numbers_1', '1'), ('Numbers_1', '2'), ('Numbers_1', '3'),
    ('Numbers_TEST', '0'), ('Numbers_TEST', '1'), ('Numbers_TEST', '2'), ('Numbers_TEST', '3'),
    ('Numbers_TEST', '4'), ('Numbers_TEST', '5'), ('Numbers_TEST', '6'), ('Numbers_TEST', '7'), ('Numbers_TEST', '8')
]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(sheets_index, names=['Id1','Id2'])

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'TYPE': ['AA','aa','Aa','aA','DD','dd','Dd','dD','11','AA','11','aa','11','Aa','11','aA','11'],
    'DATE': ['BB','bb','Bb','bB','CC','cc','Cc','cC','22','BB','22','bb','22','Bb','22','bB','22'],
    'OTHER': ['CC','cc','Cc','cC','BB','bb','Bb','bB','33','CC','33','cc','33','Cc','33','cC','33'],
    'SOURCE': ['DD','dd','Dd','dD','AA','aa','Aa','aA','XX','Start: Test_function1','Start: Test_function2','dd','','End: Test_function1','','zz','End: Test_function2']
},
    index=index
)

command_list = ["AA", "dd", "DD"]
warning_list = ["Dd", "dD"]
ingenium_list = ["CC", "BB"]

col_name_type = 'TYPE'
col_name_other = 'OTHER'
col_name_source = 'SOURCE'
df_filtered_command = df[df[col_name_type].isin(command_list)]
df_filtered_warnings = df[df[col_name_type].isin(warning_list)]
df_filtered_other = df[df[col_name_other].isin(ingenium_list)]

df_final_command = df_filtered_command[(df_filtered_command[col_name_source].str.endswith('001', na=False)) | 
(df_filtered_command[col_name_source].str.contains("a"))]

list_of_commands = df[col_name_source].dropna().tolist()

new_df = pd.DataFrame({}, columns = df.columns)

new_df = new_df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)

for value in list_of_commands:
    if 'Start: ' in value:
        value_to_match = value[6:]
        idx_start = df[df[col_name_source].str.contains(value_to_match, na = False)].first_valid_index()
        idx_end = df[df[col_name_source].str.contains(value_to_match, na = False)].last_valid_index()
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df.loc[idx_start:idx_end, :]]) 
        new_df = new_df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)

print(f'\n {new_df} \n')
```

Comment: Please post your data as text to replicate the problem by copy-pasting.

Comment: @Mortz updated my code to add in the dataframe I was testing with, thanks

Comment: `pd.concat()` can be expensive. Try populating a list of `df`s and do one `pd.concat()` at the end.

Comment: @MoseWintner Good idea, thanks! is the only way to add a blank row between the list of df's to keep adding my empty df after each new segment is added?

Comment: That's how I'd do it -- you could append a one-row "blank" dataframe to your list of `df`s just after appending each `df`.

Comment: @MoseWintner Thanks, I did just that and it's definitely faster! (If only I could speed up the styling I do later), if you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll credit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.concat()` can be expensive! Try populating a list of dfs and do one `pd.concat()` at the end.

Comment: Awesome, this helped a lot!